# Build a pytorch model wrap around another pytorch model

Tags: pytorch

Is it possible to wrap a pytorch model inside another pytorch module? I could not do it the normal way like in transfer learning (simply concatenating some more layers) because in order to get the intended value for the next 'layer', I need to wait the last layer of the first module to generate multiple outputs (say 100) and to use all those outputs to get the value for the next 'layer' (say taking the max of those outputs). I tried to define the integrated model as something like the following:

```
class integrated(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(integrated, self)._init_()

    
    def forward(self, x):

        model = VAE(
        encoder_layer_sizes=args.encoder_layer_sizes,
        latent_size=args.latent_size,
        decoder_layer_sizes=args.decoder_layer_sizes,
        conditional=args.conditional,
        num_labels=10 if args.conditional else 0).to(device)
        device = torch.device('cpu')
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(r'...'))  # the first model is saved somewhere else beforehand
        model.eval()

        temp = []
        for j in range(100):
                x = model(x)
                temp.append(x)

        y=max(temp)

        return y
```

The reason I would like to do that is the library I need to use requires the input itself to be a pytorch module. Otherwise I could simply leave the last part outside of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes you can definitely use a Pytorch module inside another Pytorch module.** The way you are doing this in your example code is a bit unusual though, as external modules (`VAE`, in your case) are more often initialized in the `__init__` function and then saved as attributes of the main module (`integrated`). Among other things, this avoids having to reload the sub-module every time you call `forward`.

One other thing that looks a bit funny is your for loop over repeated invocations of `model(x)`. If there is no randomness involved in `model`'s evaluation, then you would only need a single call to `model(x)`, since all 100 calls will give the same value. So assuming there is some randomness, you should consider whether you can get the desired effect by batching together 100 copies of `x` and using a single call to `model` with this batched input. This ultimately depends on additional information about why you are calling this function multiple times on the same input, but either way, using a single batched evaluation will be a *lot* faster than using many unbatched evaluations.